# Example of infinitely differentiable real valued function in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ which is not analytic at origin.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

If $n=1$, then

$$ f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 &~\text{for}~~ x \le 0 \\
e^{-\frac{1}{x^{2}}} &~\text{for}~~ x >0.
\end{cases}
$$
is infinitely differentiable but not analytic at the origin, because its Taylor series around origin does not equal $f(x)$ for $x >0$. Can I extend this function as follows:

$$ f(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})=
\begin{cases}
0 &~\text{for}~~ x_{1}x_{2}...x_{n} \ \le 0 \\
e^{-\frac{1}{x_{1}^{2}x_{2}^{2}...x_{n}^{2}}} &~\text{for}~~ x_{1}x_{2}...x_{n} >0.
\end{cases}
$$
But how I will check it is infinitely differentiable, because I need to check differentiability at some other points including origin. Please help me to figure out how we can extend $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $f(x)=e^{-1/(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} x_k^{2})}$ for $x\neq 0$ and $0$ for $x=0$. It is clear that this functin is $C^{\infty}$ and not analytic

Comment: To check its differentiability at origin, do I need to check all its derivative at origin or I can use the fact that result holds for $n=1$ ?

Comment: $\sum x_i^{2}$ is infinitely  differentiable and composition of infinitely differentiable functions is infinitely differentiable. @ManojKumar

Comment: Are you using expansion of exponential to prove this ?

Comment: @ManojKumar Not necessary. If $g:\mathbb R^{n} \to \mathbb R$ is smooth then $e^{g(x)}$  is smooth. This is a consequence of chain rule for differentiation.

Comment: Sorry, I may be asking a silly question, but here $g$ is not smooth at origin.

Comment: At the origin derivatives of all orders exist and they are all $0$. @ManojKumar